# How to check if a record exists in a table from another table?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am new to java programming and I am using Spring Boot. I am currently working on a database 2 tables: 'Billing' and 'Request' (both of them have same column 'billing_cycle'). And I was stucked and wondering if what is the way of checking if a record exists in 'Billing' table from 'Request' table base on the column 'billing_cycle' (it would also check if the startDate and endDate matched the records from 'request' table to 'billing' table. If it exists, it would display the existing records. If not, it will display a custom exception.

Here is my database:
['Billing table'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmzqX.png)

['Request' table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gttVX.png)

Comment: Surely it should be a foreign key from Request to Billing? Then the FK constraints can solve the problem completely, without any programming.

Answer (score 0):

You should use foreign-key constrains.

You can normalize the billing table(Remove start_data, end_date, billing_cycle columns and add Request_id as a foreign from Request table).

And If you are not doing so, then you have to extract row from billing table base on billing cycle and list of requests from request table, compare them manually(use for loops and if conditions) them throw your custom exception.